# Axios always return [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, axios

In the catch block, Axios does not return errors in the form of JSON.

Signup page

```
  const handleSignup = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const res = await axios({
        url: 'http://10.0.2.2:8080/signup',
        method: 'POST',
        data: { name, email, password },
      })
      Alert.alert(res.data.message)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    } finally {
      setIsLoading(false)
    }
  }
```

Server side

```
return res.status(400).json({ data: { message: 'Email already exists.' } })
```

I expected it to return the error message 'Email already exists,' but it returned [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400]. I've tried various approaches, but I'm not getting the expected result.

Comment: Perhaps it could be a CORS problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per docs [Handling Errors](https://axios-http.com/docs/handling_errors)

access error response body in the catch block via `error.response.data`

in your case:

```
catch (err) {
      console.error(err.response.data.data.message);
}
```